# Conveniently copy std::vector<unsigned char> to input stream (std::istream) object

Tags: c++, vector, copy, istream, unsigned-char

I'm trying to make use of a function which comes in a 3rd party lib and expects an input stream object in which binary file data is transported.

Signature looks like that:

```
doSomething(const std::string& ...,
          const std::string& ...,
          std::istream& aData,
          const std::string& ...,
          const std::map<std::string, std::string>* ...,
          long ...,
          bool ...);
```

Since I can't alter/change this 3rd party lib/function, I have to adapt in "my" code. In the calling place, I have a std::vector which contains the data which is expected to be passed in an istream object. Currently I copy the vector to the stream, by iterating over it and using the << operator to copy byte by byte.

I strongly suspect that there might be a more effective/convenient way but couldn't find anything useful up to now. Any help/your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Best,
JR

Comment: I don't see how you expect to **write** to an **input** stream.

Comment: Yes, how exactly do you use the << operator on an **istream**?

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319813/overloading-operator-for-c-stl-containers/9320896#9320896

Comment: @BillyONeal He could be using an iostream? It inherits from both istream and ostream.

Comment: std::iostream is what I currently use:

`std::iostream ss;
for( int i = 0; i < fileData.size(); i++ )
{
 ss << fileData[i];
}`

Comment: No Wait, I've put too much trust into IntelliSense. It didn't compile :) for obvious reasons....

Comment: Can't you pass an `std::ifstream` directly to the function?

Comment: @Agentlien: Then he'd have to specify that. As far as one can tell from the question he's trying to write to a `std::istream` and that's not allowed/possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vector<unsigned char> values;
// ...

stringstream ioss;    
copy(values.begin(), values.end(),
     ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(ioss,","));

// doSomething(a, b, ioss, d, e, f, g);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

`stringstream ss;    
copy(values.begin(), values.end(),
     ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(ss,""));'
works perfectly!

Answer (score 16):

You can use a `vector` of characters as an underlying buffer for an input stream without copying the contents of the vector:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> my_vec;
my_vec.push_back('a');
my_vec.push_back('b');
my_vec.push_back('c');
my_vec.push_back('\n');

// make an imput stream from my_vec
std::stringstream is;
is.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_vec[0]), my_vec.size());

// dump the input stream into stdout
std::cout << is.rdbuf();
```

---

@NeilKirk reports that [the above method of using `pubsetbuf` is non-portable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/setbuf).

One portable way is to use `boost::iostreams` library. This is how to construct an input stream from a vector without copying its contents:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char> my_vec;
    my_vec.push_back('a');
    my_vec.push_back('b');
    my_vec.push_back('c');
    my_vec.push_back('\n');

    // Construct an input stream from the vector.
    boost::iostreams::array_source my_vec_source(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_vec[0]), my_vec.size());
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> is(my_vec_source);

    // Dump the input stream into stdout.
    std::cout << is.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: The pointer to the vector data is easily invalidated. Nevertheless, the temporarity of the stringstream makes it reasonably safe. With that in mind, it's a good answer.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work, and doesn't on VS2015