# Overloading operator<<() for stl containers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload `operator<<()` (i.e. inserter operator) for stl containers (e.g `vector`, `list`, `array`) (i.e. any container that support range-based for loop and whose `value_type` also has overload for `operator<<()`). I have written the following template function

```
template <template <class...> class TT, class ...T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const TT<T...>& c)
{
    out << "[ ";

    for(auto x : c)
    {
        out << x << " ";
    }

    out << "]";
}
```

It works for `vector` and `list`. But it gives error when I try to call it for `array`

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    list<double> ld = {1.2, 2.5, 3.3};
    array<int, 3> aa = {1, 2, 3};

    cout << v << endl;  // okay
    cout << ld << endl; // okay
    cout << aa << endl; // error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
                        // cout << aa << endl;
                        //         ^
}
```

Why it does not work for `array`?
Is there any work around to overcome this problem?

I have searched in the internet and SO to find if there is a way to overload `operator<<()` for stl containers.
I have read answers in [overloading << operator for c++ stl containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319813/overloading-operator-for-c-stl-containers), but it does not answer my question.
And answers in [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) seems complecated to me.

g++ version:
`g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`

Compile command:
`g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: Your operator fails to return a value despite not returning void.

Comment: Well, you either go with the complicated answers from the question you linked (complication is required) or you write different overloads for different containers. There are only a handful containers after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `template <class...> class TT`. This parameter is for a template, any template that accepts any number of **type** parameters.

Now look at `std::array<class T, std::size_t N>`. This template doesn't accept a **type** as the second parameter. It accepts an integral constant.

So it cannot be an argument to the template function you defined, and template argument deduction fails on account of it.

As for making it work, the simplest way is to provide a (templated) overload that accepts only `std::array`. The template parameters will be the (deduced) array parameters.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, std::array<T, N> const& a)
{
    out << "[ ";

    for(auto x : a)
    {
        out << x << " ";
    }

    out << "]";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: With this overload it works with `std::array`. But does not with C style array. Do I need another overload for that?

Comment: @army007 - Sadly, yes. `(ostream& out, T (&a)[N])`. At this point, you may want to move the printing logic to a template that accepts iterators. And turn the *many* overloads to simple wrappers which forward to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your overload will not work for `std::array` because it does not match the template that `std::array` uses.  Unlike all the other standard containers `std::array` has a non type template parameter in its template parameter list.  It is defined like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array;
```

This will not work with `template <template <class...> class TT, class ...T>` as that only uses types and does not allow for the non type, `std::size_t N`, part.

If you add this overload it should work

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, std::array<T, N>& c)
{
    out << "[ ";

    for(auto x : c)
    {
        out << x << " ";
    }

    out << "]";

    return out;
}
```

---

Also note that you are not returning `out` in your overload.  This is undefined behavior as you tell the compiler you are returning something but you fail to do so.

Comment: @tobi303 Good call.  Meant to say *non type template parameter*